# Might the lack of Flu this year cause a problem creating next years flu vaccine?

Tags: vaccination, influenza

According to [this article](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/health/flu-cases-covid-england-phe-latest-b1805124.html), the UK lockdowns have had the effect of virtually eliminating Flu. As most of Europe/ The World has seen similar lockdowns, my expectation is that this would be reflected in other countries too.

As Flu is an ever-changing virus, [existing outbreaks](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-20611937) are used to determine what next years Flu Vaccine should be.

> The World Health Organization (WHO) has a global network of 147
> laboratories in 110 countries monitoring influenza outbreaks.
>
> The data collected informs which strains should be vaccinated against
> for the next winter.

The aforementioned article details this is usually a challenging process.

So, with the lack of Flu this year, will this pose a problem for those making a Flu vaccine?